# Plug external authorization to camunda

Tags: activiti, camunda

Now I am trying to migrate activiti BP to camunda. In our bpmns we widely use activiti:candidateStarterGroups="some permission whithin our system" in combination with startableByUser(someInternalUserId) and implemented custom  GroupManager which extends activiti's GroupEntityManager. As far as i can see the latter interface is not an extention point in the camunda API.

And I wonder how do I connect group/permission provider to camunda?

I dug the samples and manuals for couple of hours with no success. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since 7.10 and modeller 2.2.3 startable in tasklist and startUser/Group are configurable.